# Calculated Empirical Variance is negative (python, pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, covariance, variance

I have a data encoded to one cluster each, and I am trying to calculate the empirical mean and variance of each cluster. I will use `N` as batchsize (in other words, number of data), `D` as a dimension of each data, and `K` as a number of cluster.

`x` is a input data, which has a size of `(N, D)`, and `enc` is a one-hot encodings of the data `x` with a size of `(N, D)`. Each row of `enc` is a one-hot vector. For example, if the i-th row of `x` is in k-th cluster, the i-th row of `enc` will have 1 in k-th column and have 0 in others.

In my code, I have calculated the mean and the variance as followings:

```py
def get_mean_var(x, enc):
    n_K = (torch.sum(enc, dim=0) + 1e-10)[:,None] 
    mu_e = enc.t() @ x / n_K
    encoded_mu = torch.matmul(enc, mu_e)
    var_e = enc.t() @ ((x - encoded_mu ) ** 2) / n_K + 1e-10
    return mu_e, var_e
```

'n_K' sums the number of elements in each cluster. 'mu_e' sums 'x' for each cluster, then divide it by corresponding 'n_K'. `encoded_mu` shows the corresponding `mu_e` for each `x`, which then is used for calculating `var_e`. (I only need diagonals of the covariance.) I used `1e-10` to prevent form zero division.

However, during using this code, I found that `var_e` shows negative value often, which shouldn't be valid as far as I know.

Before this, I used the following for the `var_e`, which also showed negative value.

```py
var_e = enc.t() @ (x ** 2) / n_K - mu_e ** 2 + 1e-10
```

In both cases, I want to know where I did make mistake. Also, if there is a better way to code this, I will be very happy to know.

Edit:

I found that sampled variance should have `n_K - 1` as a denominator and I slightly changed the code.

```py
def get_mean_var(x, enc):
    n_K = (torch.sum(enc, dim=0) + 1e-10)[:,None] 
    mu_e = enc.t() @ x / n_K
    encoded_mu = torch.matmul(enc, mu_e)
    var_e = enc.t() @ ((x - encoded_mu ) ** 2) / (n_K-1) + 1e-10
    return mu_e, var_e
```

However it is still giving me negative value and I don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem of the code was the numerical instability due to how computers calculate float. When dealing with very small float, it could be actually interpreted as a negative value. Actually, that was already in my concern which is the reason I added 1e-10 for each term that could be near zero, but after evaluating misinterpreted values, I finally came to the conclusion that 1e-10 was not large enough to correct the error. Therefor, I changed the code as

```py
def get_mean_var(x, enc):
    n_K = (torch.sum(enc, dim=0) + 1e-6)[:,None] 
    mu_e = enc.t() @ x / n_K
    encoded_mu = torch.matmul(enc, mu_e)
    var_e = enc.t() @ ((x - encoded_mu ) ** 2) / (n_K - 1) + 1e-6
    return mu_e, var_e
```

Now the code is working as I intended with no negative value or NaN or whatsoever. So, in conclusion, just a tiny bit larger epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate empirical variance

def empirical_variance(list_numbers):
# Calculate the mean of the list
mean = sum(list_numbers) / len(list_numbers)

```
# Calculate the squared differences
squared_differences = [ (num - mean)**2 for num in list_numbers ]

# Calculate the empirical variance
empirical_variance = sum(squared_differences) / (len(list_numbers) - 1)

# Return the result
if empirical_variance < 0:
    return 0
else:
    return empirical_variance
```

here is the right code, you are welcome)

Comment: This code is just giving 0 if the empirical variance is zero, however as far as I know it is impossible for variance to be negative in the first place. I feel like this is not a fundamental solution but just a way to bypass the problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.